# SQLエラー(1064)について

Tags: sql

HeidiSQL 9.4.0.5125を使い
以下のサイトの2-4をそのままコピペし、テーブル名を `tmptreeagency` 、カラムを `name` に変更しました。
http://www.geocities.jp/mickindex/database/db_tree_ns.html#LocalLink-level

そうすると、

> SQL エラー (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax. Check the manual
>   that corresponds  to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near INTEGER) + 1, ` `) AS name FROM tmptreeagency Mgrs,
>   tmptreeagency MidMgrs, tmpt' at line 1

とエラーがでます。

何度もやり直していますがエラーが直りません。

エラーの原因を教えていただけるでしょうか。

実際のSQL文です

```
SELECT LPAD(Mgrs.name, LENGTH(Mgrs.name) + CAST(COUNT(*) AS INTEGER) + 1, ' ') AS name
  FROM tmptreeagency Mgrs, tmptreeagency MidMgrs, tmptreeagency Workers
 WHERE Mgrs.lft BETWEEN MidMgrs.lft AND MidMgrs.rgt
   AND MidMgrs.lft BETWEEN Workers.lft AND Workers.rgt
GROUP BY Mgrs.name, Mgrs.lft
ORDER BY MAX(Mgrs.lft);
```

Comment: 参考にされている記事では`AS INTEGER) + 1, ' ')` となっていますが、エラーメッセージでは `AS INTEGER) + 1, )` となっている（`' '`が抜けている）様に見受けられます。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。' 'が抜けているのはこちらの記載ミスでした。' 'をいれてもエラーは出てしまいます。

Comment: 単にコピペして自明の変更を施しただけのつもりでも、何かしらの誤りを混入してしまうことはよくあります。実際にあなたが試して「エラーは出てしまいます」と言うことになってしまったSQLの方をご質問中にご記載ください。

Comment: SQLも貼った方が良いです。実際にnonameさんが使っているSQL文をそのままコピペしてください。 -- 編集コメントより

Answer (score 1):

SQLの追記ありがとうございました。ただ、今回はあなたのコピペ・編集ミスではないようで、同じSQLをPostgreSQL9.3で動かしたところ、問題なく動作しました。(データを投入していないので、元著者の意図通りかどうかまではわかりませんが、少なくともSQLエラーにはなりません。)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)上にてMySQL5.6でテストしたところ(HeidiSQL自体はMySQL以外にも使えるツールですので、DBとしてMySQLをお使いなのでしたら、その旨タグ等でお示しいただいた方がいいですね。エラーメッセージをきちんと見れば、わかるのはわかるのですが…)、`CAST(... AS INTEGER)`と言う記述が構文エラーとして扱われてしまうようです。
(yudさんの書き込みを見て、もう少し調べて修正しました。[MySQLの`CAST`では(符号付き)整数型の指定は`SIGNED [INTEGER]`となっている](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/cast-functions.html)ため、変換前の型によらず`AS SIGNED`または`AS SIGNED INTEGER`としなければ構文エラーになると言うことでした。)

とりあえず`COUNT(*)`の結果は整数型なんだから、`CAST`は要らないだろうと言うことで、こんなSQLを作ったところMySQL5.6では動作するようになりました。ご質問中にはMySQLのバージョンが明記されておりませんので、そちらの環境ではどうなるかは断言できません(HeidiSQLを通したから動かなくなると言うのはないはずです)が、お試しください。

```
SELECT LPAD(Mgrs.name, LENGTH(Mgrs.name) + COUNT(*) + 1, ' ') AS name
FROM tmptreeagency Mgrs, tmptreeagency MidMgrs, tmptreeagency Workers
WHERE Mgrs.lft BETWEEN MidMgrs.lft AND MidMgrs.rgt
 AND MidMgrs.lft BETWEEN Workers.lft AND Workers.rgt
GROUP BY Mgrs.name, Mgrs.lft
ORDER BY MAX(Mgrs.lft);
```

---

(ちなみにこのSQLの方はPostgreSQL9.3では動きませんでした。`LPAD`がDBMS依存だと言うことはリンク先の記事に書いてありますが、細部の微妙な違いまで含めて複数のDBMSで動作するSQLを書くのは大変なようです。)

Comment: 無事エラーなく、実行することができました！ありがとうございました

Comment: @noname さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。私の回答中のSQLは使えたようですが、説明文中に誤りがありましたので、修正しました。ご一読ください。

Answer (score 1):

MySQLのようなので、INTEGERではなく、SIGNEDでは？
こちらでCAST部分のみ試してみたところ、INTEGERだと構文エラーになりました。

Comment: 無事エラーなく、実行することができました！ありがとうございました